# What is the most appropriate opposite of "Select All"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, american-english, antonyms

Is it more appropriate to use "Deselect All" or "Select None" or some other phrase to indicate the opposite of "Select All"?

Context: A toggle button in a piece of software that will select all items on screen, then change title to indicate it will clear the selected state of all items on screen

Comment: I would go with _Clear Selection_. Another alternative, though rarely used, would be _Unselect All_.

Comment: You'll bet better answers to this question on the user interface design discussion than on the language discussion.

Comment: see [ux.se] -- suggesting migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I have seen in software, there is usually a Select All and Clear All (for when there are some/all selected categories) but it would also be appropriate to use Deselect All instead of Clear All.

Select None would be so that (in software terms) that NO categories are to be selected at all. Unless you assign it a specific language code (for example) to make it do the same as Clear/Deselect All.

Comment: especially for select none, which is common.

Comment: Deselect All is used in the iOS 10 Photos app. Seems more appropriate than Clear All, where that could be confused with deleting/removing all.

Comment: @JordanH - Agree. We have a radio button grid where we want a "Deselect" or "Select None" button. "Clear All" would mean you would clear all records in the entire grid (which also deselects the previously selected value), which is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

**Clear Selection**, as @ManishGiri mentions, is the most common choice among web forms.

Other options include: **Reset Form**, **Clear All**, **Reset**, **Unselect**

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Manual of Style indicates "clear" instead of deselect. But, always best to use the first dictionary term of the word.

DESELECT: Turn off (a selected option) on an electronic interface such as "deselect the SAVE CHANGES option for normal use""

CLEAR: Easy to perceive, understand, or interpret such as, "clear and precise directions"